# How to change bold font to Computer Modern when using Alegreya Package

Tags: fonts

I want to use the Alegreya font in a book for chapter headings, but would like to use Computer Modern for the body text. The thing is, `\usepackage{Alegreya}` makes the default font Alegreya. To set the body font back to Computer Modern I did this:

```
\renewcommand\rmdefault{lmr}
```

The thing is, when I try to use bold font it stays in Alegreya. I would rather it not do that, so how can I set boldface font to Computer Modern?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{pifont}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{Alegreya}
\renewcommand\rmdefault{lmr}

\begin{document}
\textbf{This is in Alegreya.} This is Computer Modern.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output of the LaTeX code.]

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `alegreya`, you're changing `\familydefault` and changing `\rmdefault` cannot give you Latin Modern everywhere except in chapter titles.

If you make the simple document

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Alegreya}

\begin{document}

\familydefault

\end{document}
```

upon compiling it you will see

> Alegreya-LF

That's the key for the following.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\alegreyafont}{\fontfamily{Alegreya-LF}\selectfont}
\chapterfont{\alegreyafont}


\begin{document}

\chapter{This is in Alegreya}

This is not.

\end{document}
```

There are other ways to change the chapter heading, `sectsty` offers the simplest interface.

[image]